# How can I get "avr-unknown-gnu-atmega328" target working?

Tags: linux, rust, cross-compiling, avr

I have started to learn Rust where I would like to see now if embedded Rust can be used with a suitable amount of duct tape to write new programs for the old 8-bit CP/M systems I play with as a hobby.

I am therefore looking at whether I can make the "generate z80 binary for Rust" toolchain described in https://github.com/MartinezTorres/z80_babel working on Ubuntu 22.04.  (The trick is having Rust generate LLVM-IR for a known target with the same characteristics as an Z80, and then massage that into a binary).

The target suggested for LLVM-IR generation is `avr-unknown-gnu-atmega328` which I have troubles with building.

```
$ rustup target add avr-unknown-gnu-atmega328
error: toolchain 'nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu' does not contain component 'rust-std' for target 'avr-unknown-gnu-atmega328'
note: not all platforms have the standard library pre-compiled: https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/rustc/platform-support.html
help: consider using `cargo build -Z build-std` instead
$ cargo build -Z build-std --target=avr-unknown-gnu-atmega328
   Compiling core v0.0.0 (/home/..../.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core)
   Compiling rustc-std-workspace-core v1.99.0 (/home/...../.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/rustc-std-workspace-core)
   Compiling compiler_builtins v0.1.108
   Compiling libc v0.2.153
error: ran out of registers during register allocation
```

Based on https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/108232#issuecomment-1435958663 I edited Cargo.toml and tried with the --release flag which gave me these errors:

```
$ cargo build -Z build-std --target=avr-unknown-gnu-atmega328 --release
warning: `/home/..../.cargo/config` is deprecated in favor of `config.toml`
note: if you need to support cargo 1.38 or earlier, you can symlink `config` to `config.toml`
warning: `/home/..../.cargo/config` is deprecated in favor of `config.toml`
note: if you need to support cargo 1.38 or earlier, you can symlink `config` to `config.toml`
   Compiling gimli v0.28.1
   Compiling miniz_oxide v0.7.2
error[E0432]: unresolved import `alloc::sync`
 --> /home/...../.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/gimli-0.28.1/src/read/dwarf.rs:2:12
  |
2 | use alloc::sync::Arc;
  |            ^^^^ could not find `sync` in `alloc`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `alloc::sync`
 --> /home/..../.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/gimli-0.28.1/src/read/abbrev.rs:4:12
  |
4 | use alloc::sync::Arc;
  |            ^^^^ could not find `sync` in `alloc`

error: values of the type `[u8; 32768]` are too big for the current architecture
   --> /home/...../.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/miniz_oxide-0.7.2/src/inflate/stream.rs:186:5
    |
186 |     state: &mut InflateState,
    |     ^^^^^
```

I could make the arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf target work so I am possibly just missing a minor thing.

How should I approach getting the `avr-unknown-gnu-atmega328` target working for my purpose on Ubuntu 22.04 x64 (or others)?  Is another target a better choice?

Comment: Does this target has pointer-sized atomics?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I do not know.  I have just started with Rust.

Comment: It looks like it does (printed the target specification with `rustc +nightly -Zunstable-options --print target-spec-json --target avr-unknown-gnu-atmega328`).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman What does that imply?

Comment: But you know that AVR is a completely different thing than Z80? I don't see how having a compiler for AVR helps in compiling code for Z80.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts I know that.  As I describe in the question body I am trying to replicate what someone else did to generate LLVM-IR for a processor similar to a z80 and then postprocess that in to a z80 binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this target does not support compare-and-swap with atomics, which means that `Arc` is not available, which in turn means `std` is not supported. You can still use `core` and `alloc`, though.

To build only them:

```
cargo +nightly build -Z build-std=core,alloc --target=avr-unknown-gnu-atmega328 --release
```

You will also need to specify `panic = "abort"` and `#![no_std]` and `#![no_main]` and a custom panic handler and a start entry, since all of those are usually provided by `std`.

You can also specify this in `.cargo/config.toml`:

```rust
[build]
target = "avr-unknown-gnu-atmega328"

[unstable]
build-std = ["core", "alloc"]
```

Then, combined with override for using the nightly channel, the build can be as simple as `cargo build --release`.

Comment: It does not indeed, this is a relatively simple bare-metal oriented UC. Chip's datasheet recommends switching all interrupts off and then back on as a workaround for having critical section.